# Is it possible to use the Python installed by ArcGis Pro outside of it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to use the Python installed by ArcGis Pro (v1.2) linked to an IDE (PyCharm). The only Python installation in my WINDOWS system is Python 3.4 Installed by ArcGis Pro under the c:\Python34 folder (Python.exe).

I get errors of "Python.exe Access denied" both from the command line and from PyCharm. I have tried to change the permissions of the folder and its contents ticking off the "read only" option but again, I get "Access denied" errors, not only for Python.exe but also for a "License.txt" file within the Python34 Directory.

Is the Python installed by ArcGis supposed to be only used within the Product? or is there a way to make it my system's Python default?

Thanks a lot for any useful help!

Comment: "Is the Python installed by ArcGis supposed to be only used within the Product?" This hasn't been the case with earlier versions of ArcGIS Desktop, so I look forward to hearing whether that is the case with Pro. It will seriously impede our company's plans to switch over!

Comment: Hi! I have fixed python to run independent of arcgis pro. I just needed to correct some permissions on the python installation folder and now it works with PyCharm:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I create a python file and right click on it (after installing ArcGIS Pro and its Python version), I can choose "Edit with IDLE (ArcGIS Pro)"

[image: Sample Image]